# Adding a new item to list in ReactJS functional Component not updating UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list as follows

```
const[users,setUsers]=useState([]);
```

to dynamically add a new user and update the UI i have a function as below

```
const addNewUser = newUser => {
      setUsers(previousUsers=>{
            //only add user if he has not been added
            let existingUser = previousUsers.find((x)=>x.id===newUser.id);
            if(!existingUser){
                previousUsers.push(newUser);
            }
            return previousUsers;
        });
}
```

Unfortunately the above code is not updating the UI. This is weird.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `previousUsers` looks like an array of objects. But you're using `add` which is reserved for [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add).

Comment: That was a typo. I have corrected it. It's meant to be ```push``` not ```add```

Comment: you should change return code to `return [...previousUsers]`

Comment: @kiritoXF Loz...Woa! You are the Bosssss!!!! Yea, you are absolutely right. Your solution worked for me . Thank you so so much. You should make your comment as an answer so I can accept yours as the answer. Thank you so so much.

Comment: @user15155716 I don't know how to descript the reason, so just make it to a comment.

Comment: @kiritoXF Okay. That's fine. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

I would do the check outside of the set state:

```
function addNewUser(newUser) {
  const existingUser = users.find(user => user.id === newUser.id);
  if (!existingUser) {
    setUsers(prev => ([...prev, newUser]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the UI is not re-rendering is because state value is not changed.
If you want to use arrays or objects in React State, you have to create a copy of the value before modifying it.
You can find the basic example of doing it below:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const handleAdd = (todo) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.push(todo);
    setTodos(newTodos);
}
```